# Undefined method 'zero' for ... ActiveSupport::OrderedHash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Check the note below. Why is it before I do `p variant_attributes`, `blank?` method returned error, while after it, it works fine?

Ruby 1.9.2-p0 on Rails 3.0.3

```
p variant_attributes.blank?
# => NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `zero?' for {"Brocade w/ Grande Stripe backing"=>3}:ActiveSupport::OrderedHash
p variant_attributes
# => [#<VariantAttribute id: 1251, variant_id: 561, product_option_id: 838, value: "Brocade w/ Grande Stripe backing">]
p variant_attributes.blank?
# => false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `variant_attributes` is a kind of ActiveRecord collection of records (which it looks like) then it is probably because rails uses lazy loading to fetch records from the database but the `blank?` method does not trigger the actual loading.

You may want to call the `all` method on `variant_attributes` to manually trigger the loading, or if you don't want to do that, you may go for `variant_attributes.count.zero?` instead of `variant_attributes.blank?`

See [Pratik Naik's blog post about ActiveRecord 3.0](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface) query interface for the details